# why size (y axis) of imread image is bigger than real

Tags: matlab, imshow, imread

I have an image ('strawberry.jpg') 
[strawberry.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUg8m.jpg)

```
image=imread('strawberry.jpg');
imshow(image);
```

it display as below.

[image: imshowimage]

I think the x and y axis are shown in pixel of the photo. But when I try to get the size by using

```
 [x,y]=size(image)
```

Then I got x = 177 and y = 852. But the value are not close to with those that are showed in imshow image.

So, am i doing anything wrong? or [x,y]=size (image) means different size rather than pixel size that is showed in imshow image.

Thanks

Comment: Try just `[x,y,z]=size(image)`. Because `image` is a 3D array, by only allowing two outputs from `size`, you force it to make `y` equal to the product of the 2nd and 3rd dimensions.

Comment: thanks @David. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have an RGB image (i.e. 3 channels in the third dimension). When you explicitly request two outputs from `size` it returns the number of rows for the first output and the number of columns *times* the size of the third dimension (284 x 3) as [the second output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html#btzcabo-2).

If you want the true dimensions of your RGB image, you need to specify *three* outputs to size.

```
[nRows, nColumns, nChannels] = size(image);
```

Alternately, you could request a *single* output from `size` and it will yield an array of sizes where each element corresponds to the size in *that* dimension.

```
sz = size(image);
%// 177   284   3
```

Or use the second input argument to specify the dimension you care about explicitly.

```
nRows = size(image, 1);
nColumns = size(image, 2);
```